# How to add buy book button to every row in a table and print the book in area?

Tags: java, button, javafx

The code that I have bellow prints the book from the row that I press buyButton. But I want to change that. Every time I press the buyButton I need the book to apear in the "Your cart:" Area and I am stuck at that. I dont know how to make a handler for the buyButton from Controller class.
This is my View class:

```
public CustomerView(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Book Store");

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        initializeGridPane(gridPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 720, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        initializeSceneTitle(gridPane);

        initializeTableView(gridPane);

        initializeFields(gridPane);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initializeGridPane(GridPane gridPane) {
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));
    }

    private void initializeSceneTitle(GridPane gridPane) {
        Text sceneTitle = new Text("Our book colection");
        sceneTitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahome", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        gridPane.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0, 1, 3);
    }

    private void initializeTableView(GridPane gridPane) {
        table = new TableView<>();

        idColumn = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        titleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Title");
        authorColumn = new TableColumn<>("Author");
        pubDateColumn = new TableColumn<>("Published Date");
        priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
        stockColumn = new TableColumn<>("Stock");
        buyColumn = new TableColumn<>("Buy");

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));
        authorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("author"));
        pubDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("publishedDate"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        stockColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stock"));

        //final Button buyButton = new Button("Buy");

        //bibliografie pentru codul de mai jos
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view
        Callback<TableColumn<Book, Button>, TableCell<Book, Button>> cellFactory
                = //
                new Callback<TableColumn<Book, Button>, TableCell<Book, Button>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Book, Button> param) {
                        final TableCell<Book, Button> cell = new TableCell<Book, Button>() {

                            final Button buyButton = new Button("Buy");

                            @Override
                            protected void updateItem(Button item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (empty) {
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                } else {
                                    buyButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                                        Book book = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                                        System.out.println(book.getAuthor()
                                                + "   " + book.getTitle());
                                        //buyBookHandler.handle(event);
                                    });
                                    setGraphic(buyButton);
                                }

                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }
                };

        buyColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        table.getColumns().add(idColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(titleColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(authorColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(pubDateColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(priceColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(stockColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(buyColumn);
        gridPane.add(table,2, 4, 25,25);//1:0

        VBox tableViewBox = new VBox(10);
        tableViewBox.getChildren().add(table);

        showAllBooksButton = new Button("See out book colection");

        HBox viewAllBooksHBox = new HBox(10);
        viewAllBooksHBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        viewAllBooksHBox.getChildren().add(showAllBooksButton);
        gridPane.add(viewAllBooksHBox, 5, 1);

        //HBox buyButtonHBox = new HBox(10);
        //buyButtonHBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        //gridPane.add(buyButtonHBox, 0,20,2,1);
        gridPane.add(tableViewBox, 0, 5, 10, 20);

    }

    private void initializeFields(GridPane gridPane) {
        cartArea = new TextArea();
        cartArea.setEditable(false);
        cartArea.setText("Your cart: \n");

        HBox buttonsHBox = new HBox(5);
        buttonsHBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        buttonsHBox.getChildren().addAll(cartArea);
        gridPane.add(buttonsHBox, 0, 27, 2, 5);

        totalPriceLabel = new Label("Total price: ");
        gridPane.add(totalPriceLabel, 0, 32, 5, 1);
    }

    public void setBooksData(List<Book> books) {
        booksList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(books);
        table.setItems(booksList);
    }

    public void showAllBooks(EventHandler<ActionEvent> show){
        showAllBooksButton.setOnAction(show);
    }

    public void setCartArea(String msj){
        cartArea.appendText(msj);
    }

    public void setPriceTotal(int price){
        totalPriceLabel.setText(totalPriceLabel.getText() + price);
    }
```

This in my Controller class:

```
public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerView customerView;
    private final BookService bookService;
    List<Book> booksInCart = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomerController(CustomerView customerView, BookService bookService) {
        this.customerView = customerView;
        this.bookService = bookService;

        //this.customerView.setBuyButtonHandler(new BuyBook());
        this.customerView.showAllBooks(new ViewAllBooks());
    }

    private class ViewAllBooks implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        private List<Book> books;
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            books = bookService.findAll();
            customerView.setBooksData(books);
        }
    }

    private class BuyBook implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        private String title;
        private int stock;
        private Book selectedBook;
        private int price = 0;
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            selectedBook = customerView.getSelectedBook();
            //booksInCart.add(selectedBook);
            title = selectedBook.getTitle();
            stock = selectedBook.getStock();

            if(stock > 0){
                selectedBook.setStock(stock - 1);
                customerView.setCartArea(title);

                price += selectedBook.getPrice();
                customerView.setPriceTotal(price);
            }
            else {
                customerView.setCartArea("Sold out!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a model class? Typically you would have an `ObservableList<Book>` in the model; your list view can use that list as its `items` list, and your button action can add the appropriate book to the list, which will result in the list view automatically updating. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868391/using-javafx-controller-without-fxml/36873768#36873768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Approach**

The approach here is as outlined by James_D in comments:

> Typically you would have an ObservableList in the model; your list view can use that list as its items list, and your button action can add the appropriate book to the list, which will result in the list view automatically updating.

For the implementation the logic described in the comment, see this `BuyCell` class, where `Cart` is the part of the model managing the items list in the shopping cart.

```
class BuyCell extends TableCell<Book, Void> {
    private final Button buy = new Button("Buy");

    public BuyCell(Cart cart) {
        buy.setOnAction(e ->
                cart.addBook(getTableRow().getItem())
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic(empty ? null : buy);
    }
}
```

**Complete Example**

You should model your domain (a book store) and then write the code to make use of the modeled domain.

You need something to represent a Book:

```
record Book(String title, String author) {}
```

And something to represent a shopping cart:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.Optional;

class Cart {
    private final ObservableList<CartItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<CartItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        Optional<CartItem> cartItem =
                items.stream()
                        .filter(item -> item.getBook().equals(book))
                        .findFirst();

        if (cartItem.isPresent()) {
            cartItem.get().setQuantity(
                    cartItem.get().getQuantity() + 1
            );
        } else {
            items.add(new CartItem(book, 1));
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        items.clear();
    }
}
```

And something to represent a line item in the shopping cart:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

class CartItem {
    private final Book book;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty quantity;

    public CartItem(Book book, int quantity) {
        this.book = book;
        this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }
}
```

And something to represent all of the available books in the store and the current shopping cart.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

class BookStoreModel {
    private final ObservableList<Book> books = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final Cart cart = new Cart();

    public BookStoreModel() {
        books.addAll(
                new Book("The Seven Lamps of Architecture", "John Ruskin"),
                new Book("Collapse: How Societies Choose to Fail or Succeed", "Jared Diamond")
        );
    }

    public ObservableList<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public Cart getCart() {
        return cart;
    }
}
```

Then you need a UI for it:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

class BookStoreUI {
    public TableView<Book> createAvailableBooksView(
            ObservableList<Book> books, Cart cart
    ) {
        TableView<Book> availableBooks = new TableView<>(books);

        TableColumn<Book, String> titleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Title");
        titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(p ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().title())
        );
        titleColumn.setPrefWidth(250);

        TableColumn<Book, String> authorColumn = new TableColumn<>("Author");
        authorColumn.setCellValueFactory(p ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().author())
        );

        TableColumn<Book, Void> buyColumn = new TableColumn<>("Buy");
        buyColumn.setMaxWidth(70);
        buyColumn.setCellFactory(p ->
                new BuyCell(cart)
        );

        //noinspection unchecked
        availableBooks.getColumns().addAll(titleColumn, authorColumn, buyColumn);

        availableBooks.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS);

        return availableBooks;
    }

    public TableView<CartItem> createPurchasesView(Cart cart) {
        TableView<CartItem> purchases = new TableView<>(cart.getItems());
        TableColumn<CartItem, String> purchasedTitleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Title");
        purchasedTitleColumn.setCellValueFactory(p ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getBook().title())
        );
        purchasedTitleColumn.setPrefWidth(250);

        TableColumn<CartItem, Integer> quantityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
        quantityColumn.setMaxWidth(70);
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(p ->
                p.getValue().quantityProperty().asObject()
        );

        //noinspection unchecked
        purchases.getColumns().addAll(purchasedTitleColumn, quantityColumn);

        purchases.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS);

        return purchases;
    }

    public Parent createCartControl(Cart cart) {
        Button clear = new Button("Clear");
        clear.setOnAction(e -> cart.clear());
        clear.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(cart.getItems()));

        return clear;
    }
}
```

And a widget for the Buy button.

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

class BuyCell extends TableCell<Book, Void> {
    private final Button buy = new Button("Buy");
    private final StackPane container = new StackPane(buy);

    public BuyCell(Cart cart) {
        container.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        buy.setOnAction(e ->
                cart.addBook(getTableRow().getItem())
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic(empty ? null : container);
    }
}
```

And an application to tie it all together.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BookStoreApp extends Application {
    private final BookStoreModel model = new BookStoreModel();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BookStoreUI ui = new BookStoreUI();

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                new Label("Available Books"),
                ui.createAvailableBooksView(model.getBooks(), model.getCart()),
                new Label("Shopping Cart"),
                ui.createPurchasesView(model.getCart()),
                ui.createCartControl(model.getCart())
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setPrefSize(500, 400);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Then you end up with something like this:

[image: screenshot]

**Additional resources**

- [Eden provides a tutorial on TableView cell customization](https://edencoding.com/tableview-customization-cellfactory/), it is more comprehensive than what you need, but it may be worth your time reviewing it.
- Here is an example of [buttons in a TableView with FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724948/accessing-buttons-in-tableview). Doing it without FXML is pretty much similar.